# ammonium tartrate + lead tartrate=?

Tags: solubility

From Googlebooks First Outlines of a Dictionary of Solubilities of Chemical Substances  By Frank Humphreys Storer:

> I find that lead tartrate is dissolved by tartrate of ammonia.

What is the final product?

Answer (score 2):

The addition of ammonium tartrate turns lead tartrate into a water-soluble tartrato complex: 
\[\ce{Pb(tart) + tart^{2-} <=>> [Pb(tart)2]^2-}\]